# Make nested Http calls inside switchMap

Tags: angular, rxjs, switchmap

```
if (this.role === 'admin' || this.role === 'superadmin') {
  this.organizationService.getDropdownOrganizations().pipe(
    tap(availableOrganizations => {
      this.availableOrganizations = availableOrganizations;
    }),
    switchMap(availableOrganizations => {
      return this.projectService.getProjects(availableOrganizations[0]?.id);
    }),
  ).subscribe(availableProjects => {
    this.availableProjects = availableProjects;
    this.getNotifications();
  });
} else {
  this.getNotifications();
}
```

Hello Everyone,

In the code above i pass orgId to project service and subscribe to availableProjects

My question is I want to make another request same as getProjects() to getUsers() and pass orgId and get both projects and users with this.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot we don't know. I'm assuming `getProjects` and `getUsers` both emit once and then complete. If that's the case, you can use `forkJoin` to process both at once and return the results for both once they're complete.

That could look something like:

```
if (this.role === 'admin' || this.role === 'superadmin') {
  this.organizationService.getDropdownOrganizations().pipe(
    tap(availableOrganizations => 
      this.availableOrganizations = availableOrganizations
    ),
    switchMap(availableOrganizations => forkJoin({
      projects: this.projectService.getProjects(availableOrganizations[0]?.id),
      users: this.projectService.getUsers(availableOrganizations[0]?.id)
    })),
  ).subscribe(({projects, users}) => {
    this.availableProjects = projects;
    this.availableUsers = users;
    this.getNotifications();
  });
} else {
  this.getNotifications();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use forkJoin to do that if you want them to be executed in the same time.

```
switchMap(availableOrganizations => {
  return forkJoin([
      this.projectService.getProjects(availableOrganizations[0]?.id),
      this.projectService.getUsers(availableOrganizations[0]?.id);
  ]);
}),
```

Then you can access both values as properties of array passed to next stream operator. I'd advise to use array destructuring there:

```
).subscribe(([availableProjects, users ]) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the same cold observable and share the result with `shareReplay`

```
if (this.role === 'admin' || this.role === 'superadmin') {
  const availableOrganizations$ = this.organizationService.getDropdownOrganizations().pipe(
    shareReplay(1),
  );

  availableOrganizations$.subscribe(availableOrganizations => this.availableOrganizations = availableOrganizations);

  availableOrganizations$.pipe(
    switchMap(availableOrganizations => this.projectService.getProjects(availableOrganizations[0]?.id)),
  ).subscribe(availableProjects => {
    this.availableProjects = availableProjects;
    this.getNotifications();
  });

  // TODO: same for user as the previous block
} else {
  this.getNotifications();
}
```